# Using Spring data JPA, how can I create a dynamic query for a filter form

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a form that will generate the sql query for me based on the form input.

For example, I have a table People[id, name, age], and a form with two fields: 
Name and age.

If all the two fields are completed on the form, the query was going to be like this:

```
 List<People> findByNamendAge(String name, Int age);
```

But if only the name is filled, I want to show all the people that correspond to just the name, even though the age is left blank.

(of course, in this example I could create a `findByName(String name)` and a `finByAge(Int age)`, and a simple if/else would do, but my real problem envolves a filter that contains a large amount of inputs)

Comment: I sugest you look into doing query-by-example. Spring data has [a module for this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/query-by-example).

Comment: You should look at using the QueryDSL extension for Spring Data  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449410/what-is-the-best-solution-for-filtering-results-in-spring-data-jpa-with-many-pro/26450224#26450224 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/33647084/1356423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JPA CriteriaAPI for that. You can find an example here:

[Conditional where clause in JPA criteria query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097652/conditional-where-clause-in-jpa-criteria-query)

Comment: yeah, I've heard of the CriteriaAPI, but I was trying to avoid the large amounts of if/else that this approach would require.

Comment: @BrunoGois, why do you think it would? Just make a 1to1 linkage of form fields with model fields, so you know exactly which field is filled with value.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I'm sorry, but care to explain exactly what a 1to1 linkage of form fields with model fields means? Never heard of this approach

Comment: @BrunoGois, mapping can be produced in a bunch of ways. One of the more common is `Java Beans` specification that declares "properties". For example, a `Person` has property "Age" (accessed on a bean by `getAge()`) and form field has "Age" field. This is a 1to1 as long as there are no other fields on a form titled "Name". you can build your criteria this way.