# Do left outer join only if condition satisfies in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to JPA and trying to do a left outer join, only if a condition is satisfied in the native JPA query.

Native query is as shown below. Here I would like to do `A left outer join B` with the where condition, only if a given flag `toJoin` is true in application:

```
select a.id, a.name from A left outer join B on A.id = B.aid where b.name="some_name"
```

I am not sure, how will I accommodate the `toJoin` application flag in the above native JPA query in my JPA repository.

**EDIT**

I was just trying to achieve the same in mysql with the help of `CASE WHEN` and sample condition as follows:

```
select a.id from A a, case when 1=2 then left outer join B b ON a.id = b.aid end limit 2;
```

But I am getting syntaxt error.

Comment: why can't you have two queries inside your condition? `IF <select ...> else <select ...>`

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I am not sure, how will I write the IF clause in my JPA repository. If possible, could you please give a short example? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097652/conditional-where-clause-in-jpa-criteria-query

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I went through the link. But as of now, all queries in the JPA repository are native, wherein several queries I have been doing the changes. Criteria builder has not been used so far. I am thinking, in order to follow the approach as suggested in the link, I have to make a considerable amount of changes. So I am wondering if there is any way to achieve this with the help of native query.

Comment: Why don't you just do an inner join?

Comment: Actually not all the rows in A, associated with a row in B. In the result, I want all the rows in A, regardless if it matches or not with a row in B. That's why I need to do left outer join. I want to do this left outer join only if the toJoin flag is true in the application as mentioned in OP.

Comment: What is the intention of `when 1=2`?

Comment: when 1=2, is just a representative condition. Its intent is to skip the join when the associated condition is false.

Comment: *I would like to do A left outer join B with the where condition, only if a given flag toJoin is true in application* Noway in SQL. The output structure is always definite and static whereas you want to obtain different output structure depends on the condition. Solution - test this flag in the application and execute the query either with or without JOINing depends on the flag value.

Comment: Since you are not selecting from table B, why join to it? Did you mean to `select a.id, b.someColumn` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question remains vague, however I suspect that your effort:

```
select a.id
from A a, case when 1=2 then left outer join B b on a.id = b.aid end
limit 2
```

Is meant to be:

```
select a.id, b.someColumn
from A a
left join B b on a.id = b.aid and 1=2
limit 2
```

Where `1=2` is actually some more complicated expression.